# LinearLayout not wrapping content

Tags: android, android-layout

I used LinearLayout to stack 4 images horizontally and it works well except for the height. It seems that the linearlayout is not properly wrapping its content. If I don't set the images' scale type to fitStart, they will be centered inside the linearlayout.

Here is my layout below:

[image: linearlayout]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/header1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/header2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/header3color"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:src="@drawable/header4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please don't cut off the XML. We need to see more to understand the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `adjustViewBounds` attribute to `true` for those images.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds

That should take care of that extra space you have and the LinearLayout should `wrap_content` correctly.

Comment: Whoops, I put the wrong attribute in my answer.  Just fixed it, so try adjustViewBounds

Comment: it works! I was thinking the wrong thing about this attribute.. ill be accepting this answer in 5 mins :) thanks!

Comment: Excellent!  ImageView can be tricky (perhaps buggy) with properties like padding and weights

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your `ImageView`s

Answer (score -1):

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true" to be set in your imageview's
```