# Android ImageView doesn't wrap content

Tags: android, imageview, tablelayout

Cannot solve trouble with `ImageView` inside of the TableLayout.
I am setting both `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `wrap_content`,
but some unneeded area appeares on the left and right sides.
(image is actually square shaped)

[image]

Explored similar questions
here 
[Why do I need to wrap an ImageView into a FrameLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609106/why-do-i-need-to-wrap-an-imageview-into-a-framelayout)
here
[LinearLayout not wrapping content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752769/linearlayout-not-wrapping-content)
and others

Tried

- setting `adjustViewBounds="true"`,
- setting fixed width and heigth in dp,
- played with `scalTypes`,
- wrapped into `FrameLayout`,

but nothing helps with this issue.
Why it appears, how to get rid of it and just wrap the image?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_deal_number_description"
                style="@style/ListHeadingTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/deal_number"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_deal_number"
                style="@style/ListHeadingTextStyle"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLines="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/div_under_deal_number"
            style="@style/Divider"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/descriptions_vertical_margin"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/ic_margin_right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ic_margin_right"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person_grey600_24dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"

           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_client_name_description"
            style="@style/DescriptionTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/description_value_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/description_value_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="@string/client_name_col" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_client_name"
            style="@style/ListValuesTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="2" />
    </TableRow>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you set sizes wrap_content, also you set margins.

```
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/ic_margin_right"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ic_margin_right"
```

Try to remove these arrributes or set them 0.

Comment: As you can see, this margin is only on the right side. And removing of them does not help.

Comment: Maybe it is somehow related to TableLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this happen due to your image. Try to CROP your image as fit. Your image hold extra space in left & right side even image is also transparent. Retry it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occured because of the heading.
After removing of heading from the first row of the table, ImageViews started having no margins, just wrapped content 
(to be honest I don't know exactly why).
So I just put heading out of the table layout and achieved desired:

[image]

Now the code looks like:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_deal_number_description"
            style="@style/ListHeadingTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/deal_number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_deal_number"
            style="@style/ListHeadingTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/accent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/div_under_deal_number"
                style="@style/Divider"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/descriptions_vertical_margin"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/ic_margin_right"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ic_margin_right"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_person_grey600_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_client_name_description"
                style="@style/DescriptionTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/description_value_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/description_value_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="@string/client_name_col" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_client_name"
                style="@style/ListValuesTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLines="2" />
        </TableRow>
    ...
```